# If-else choosing random option rather than basing choice off of randomly generated number

Tags: java, if-statement

This code simply doesn't seem to work. I can't seem to figure out why it isn't, but when I run it it seems to choose a random price from the options rather than go off what the temperature actually is. I'm also wondering if there would be a better way to implement what I'm trying to do rather than a huge if-else ladder. Thanks

```
public static double GetPrice ()
{
    if (temp >= 0 && temp < 50)
    {
        price = 0.50;
    }
    else if (temp >= 50 && temp <= 60)
    {
        price = 0.55;
    }
    else if (temp >= 61 && temp <= 65)
    {
        price = 0.60;
    }
    else if (temp >= 66 && temp <= 70)
    {
        price = 0.65;
    }
    else if (temp >= 71 && temp <= 75)
    {
        price = 0.75;
    }
    else if (temp >= 76 && temp <= 80)
    {
        price = 0.80;
    }
    else if (temp >= 81 && temp <= 85)
    {
        price = 0.85;
    }
    else if (temp >= 86 && temp <= 90)
    {
        price = 0.90;
    }
    else if (temp > 90)
    {
        price = 1.00;
    }

    return price;
}
```

Comment: Before you doubt that the `if-else` is doing something weird i´d rather doubt your implementation, because way way way more likely that this is the root of your mistake. But how should we answer it if we don´t know the value of temp? did you try to debug it?

Comment: Can you please add some test-cases with different values of 'temp' and their respective outputs?

Comment: Have you noticed that you could achieve the same thing without all these `if` statements ? For example, using `round` and/or `ceil` methods...

Comment: Instead of huge `if-else`s you can implement list of ranges and check them in the loop

Comment: What is temp, what is price, and where are they declared and set? We dont know the scope of these 2 variables. Also a variable like temp probably shouldn't have scope outside the function it is used in.

Comment: What happens when you step through the code with a debugger to see where the problem is?

Comment: Your code is probably doing everything correctly exactly as you posted, because you have described what it is supposed to do.  Show us what is calling `GetPrice()` and what the inputs/outputs are currently and what you want the inputs/outputs to be

Comment: Your code seems perfect just debug the value of temp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the suspicion that your problem is that you declared the method as "static" (and most likely the variables "temp" and "price" as well), while trying to use it as an instance method.

Either make the method non static, or change it so that you have to pass "temp" and return the value directly instead of saving it in a static variable first.

```
public static double GetPrice (double temp)
{
    if (temp >= 0 && temp < 50)
    {
        return 0.50;
    } else if (temp >= 50 && temp <= 60) {
        return 0.55;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When i try it out, it works how it does. What you could do to keep the code smaller is to let out the {} after the if and else if. Because that:

```
if (temp >= 0 && temp < 50)
{
    price = 0.50;
}
else if (temp >= 50 && temp <= 60)
{
    price = 0.55;
}
```

Does the same as that:

```
if (temp >= 0 && temp < 50) price = 0.50;
else if (temp >= 50 && temp <= 60) price = 0.55;
```

So you can write them all under each other.
This only works if you have only one statement after the if or else if.

Comment: I can sadly only comment here, but i want to say that the answere of ParkerHalo doesn't work always, for 63 it does set the price to 65, but it needs to be 60.  I didn't looked up why, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your code works correctly.
If you don't want to use if else chain and want to have code more complicated than nice code of ParkerHalo :) you could declare ranges and put them to list

```
public static double GetPrice()
{
    class PriceLevel
    {
        public double  theHighestVal;
        public boolean valIncluded;     // determines if < or <= comparator should be used
        public double  priceLevel;
    }
    List<PriceLevel> priceLevels = new ArrayList<PriceLevel>()
    {{
        add(new PriceLevel() {{theHighestVal=0;  valIncluded=false; priceLevel=0.0;}});
        add(new PriceLevel() {{theHighestVal=50; valIncluded=false; priceLevel=0.50;}});
        add(new PriceLevel() {{theHighestVal=60; valIncluded=true;  priceLevel=0.55;}});
        add(new PriceLevel() {{theHighestVal=65; valIncluded=true;  priceLevel=0.60;}});
        add(new PriceLevel() {{theHighestVal=70; valIncluded=true;  priceLevel=0.65;}});
        add(new PriceLevel() {{theHighestVal=75; valIncluded=true;  priceLevel=0.75;}});
        add(new PriceLevel() {{theHighestVal=80; valIncluded=true;  priceLevel=0.80;}});
        add(new PriceLevel() {{theHighestVal=85; valIncluded=true;  priceLevel=0.85;}});
        add(new PriceLevel() {{theHighestVal=90; valIncluded=true;  priceLevel=0.90;}});
    }};

    double price = 1.0;
    for (PriceLevel l : priceLevels)
    {
        if (l.valIncluded ? temp <= l.theHighestVal : temp < l.theHighestVal)
        {
            price = l.priceLevel;
            break;
        }
    }
    return price;
}
```